# How to execute same command "X" multiple times with a time delay of some number of seconds?

Tags: shell, command-line

I know how to execute multiple commands at same time but now what I need is to run the same command multiple times with some time delay between the command execution.

#### Requirements

- I don't want to use a script for this
- A single one line command to accomplish this
- Needs to run on Linux
- Need to control the number of times the command will run

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Is this sufficient? `echo 'hello'; sleep 3; echo 'goodbye'`

Comment: that is ok but I want the execute the same command for more and I would not like to use echo 'hello'; sleep 1; again same command.Basically, I would like to control the number of times that I would like to repeat the command

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use this one liner to do what you're asking:

```
$ cmd="..some command..."; for i in $(seq 5); do $cmd; sleep 1; done
```

#### Example

```
$ date
Fri Nov 22 01:37:43 EST 2013

$ cmd="echo"; for i in $(seq 5); do $cmd "count: $i"; sleep 1;done
count: 1
count: 2
count: 3
count: 4
count: 5

$ date
Fri Nov 22 01:37:51 EST 2013
```

You can adjust the `sleep ...` to what ever delay you'd like between commands, and change `cmd=...` to whatever command you want.

#### Brace expansions vs. seq cmd

You can also use brace expansions instead of the `seq` command to generate ranges of values. This is a bit more performant since the brace expansions will run in the same shell as the `for` loop. Using the subshell (`$(seq ..)`) is a little less performant, since it's spawning a subshell within the confines of the shell that the `for` loop is running.

#### Example

```
$ cmd="echo"; for i in {1..5}; do $cmd "count: $i"; sleep 1;done
count: 1
count: 2
count: 3
count: 4
count: 5
```

Comment: Why starting a subshell? Why not just `for i in {1..5}`?

Comment: @Bernhard - thanks, apparently I like using `seq` too much, I've added a section showing brace expansions.

Answer (score 19):

With `zsh`:

```
repeat 10 {date; sleep 5}
```

That runs the commands (here `date` as an example) with a 5 second sleep in between them.

If instead you want to run it every 5 second (and assuming the command takes less than 5 seconds to run):

```
typeset -F SECONDS=0; repeat 10 {date; ((n=5-SECONDS)); SECONDS=0; LC_ALL=C sleep $n}
```

(Assuming a `sleep` implementation that supports fractionnal seconds).

Comment: So simple; thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This runs the `date` command for 10 times with a 5 second delay. Change the 10 in `seq 1 10` for the number of times you want, replace `date` with the command you want and change the 5 in `sleep 5` to change the delay time.

```
for d in $(seq 1 10); do date; sleep 5; done;
```

Comment: Try not to use the back ticks, they're deprecated. Use `$(..)` instead.