# Run a command x after command y has ran n times

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to create a bash script in which I want to **execute a command x only if command y has been executed  n times successfully.**
Thanks for your help in advance!!!
And no question isn't duplicate of

- [how-to-execute-same-command-x-multiple-times-with-a-time-delay-of-some-number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102172/how-to-execute-same-command-x-multiple-times-with-a-time-delay-of-some-number)
- [how-to-run-a-command-multiple-times-using-bash-shell](https://serverfault.com/questions/273238/how-to-run-a-command-multiple-times-using-bash-shell)
- [run-command-until-successful-n-times-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30197818/run-command-until-successful-n-times-bash)

Comment: Do you want it to retry command y unlimited times until it is successful 3 times or only try 3 times total?

Comment: No I don't want it to retry , just 3 times total

Answer (score 2):

Using a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

s=0

for ((i=1;i<=3;i++)); do
    if command y; then
        ((s++))
    fi
done

if ((s==3)); then
    command x
fi
```

We set the `s` parameter to 0 to keep track of our successful command y attempts. (not really necessary but I prefer to do it)
The for loop will then run 3 times, running `command y` each time, if `command y` is successful it will add 1 to `s`.
After the loop ends, if `s` equals 3 it will run `command x`.